# Do my tables in the db "HAVE" to be plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to display Snort IPS events in my dashboard app, these events are written into a database via barnyard2. I'm going threw `rails for zombies` and they say to access info from tables out of a database the table should be plural, and the model is singular. You would then expect the table with the IPS events to be `events` and not `event`.

Barnyard2 comes with a `create_postgres` schema script. Below are the tables created by the script. They are all singular.

```
csdashboard=# \dt
                List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |    Owner    
--------+-------------------+-------+-------------
 public | data              | table | csdashboard
 public | detail            | table | csdashboard
 public | encoding          | table | csdashboard
 public | event             | table | csdashboard
 public | icmphdr           | table | csdashboard
 public | iphdr             | table | csdashboard
 public | opt               | table | csdashboard
 public | reference         | table | csdashboard
 public | reference_system  | table | csdashboard
 public | schema            | table | csdashboard
 public | sensor            | table | csdashboard
 public | sig_class         | table | csdashboard
 public | sig_reference     | table | csdashboard
 public | signature         | table | csdashboard
 public | tcphdr            | table | csdashboard
 public | udphdr            | table | csdashboard
```

I do not need or want my app to enter anything into these tables, just find and display the info.

My questions are;

1. Do I need to create a model per table that I will be getting info from?
2. Since they should be plural, will this create a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to stick with all conventions and there is an easy way to alter this one.
[You can set table name in your model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D):

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'event'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Yes.

You need a model per table. Without that you'll have big problems with `ActiveRecord`.
You'll have some other problems if your table name is not a plural of your model, once again with `ActiveRecord`.